# training a RNN in Pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I want to have an RNN model and teach it to learn generating "ihello" from "hihell". I am new in Pytorch and following the instruction in a video to write the code.
I have written two python files named `train.py` and `model.py`.
this is `model.py`:

```python
#----------------- model for teach rnn hihell to ihello
#-----------------  OUR MODEL ---------------------
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import autograd

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model,self).__init__()
        self.rnn=nn.RNN(input_size=input_size,hidden_size=hidden_size,batch_first=True)
    def forward(self,x,hidden):
        #Reshape input in (batch_size,sequence_length,input_size)
        x=x.view(batch_size,sequence_length,input_size)
        #Propagate input through RNN
        #Input:(batch,seq+len,input_size)
        out,hidden=self.rnn(x,hidden)
        out=out.view(-1,num_classes)
        return hidden,out
    def init_hidden(self):
        #Initialize hidden and cell states
        #(num_layers*num_directions,batch,hidden_size)
        return autograd.Variable(torch.zeros(num_layers,batch_size,hidden_size))
```

and this is `train.py`:

```python
"""----------------------train for teach rnn to hihell to ihello--------------------------"""
#-----------------  DATA PREPARATION ---------------------
#Import
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import autograd
from model import Model
import sys


idx2char=['h','i','e','l','o']
#Teach hihell->ihello
x_data=[0,1,0,2,3,3]#hihell
y_data=[1,0,2,3,3,4]#ihello
one_hot_lookup=[[1,0,0,0,0],#0
                [0,1,0,0,0],#1
                [0,0,1,0,0],#2
                [0,0,0,1,0],#3
                [0,0,0,0,1]]#4
x_one_hot=[one_hot_lookup[x] for x in x_data]
inputs=autograd.Variable(torch.Tensor(x_one_hot))
labels=autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor(y_data))
""" ----------- Parameters Initialization------------"""
num_classes = 5
input_size = 5  # one hot size
hidden_size = 5  # output from LSTM to directly predict onr-hot
batch_size = 1  # one sequence
sequence_length = 1  # let's do one by one
num_layers = 1  # one layer RNN
"""-----------------  LOSS AND TRAINING ---------------------"""
#Instantiate RNN model
model=Model()
#Set loss and optimizer function
#CrossEntropyLoss=LogSoftmax+NLLLOSS
criterion=torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.1)

"""----------------Train the model-------------------"""
for epoch in range(100):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss=0
    hidden=model.init_hidden()
    sys.stdout.write("Predicted String:")
    for input,label in zip(inputs,labels):
        #print(input.size(),label.size())
        hidden,output=model(input,hidden)
        val,idx=output.max(1)
        sys.stdout.write(idx2char[idx.data[0]])
        loss+=criterion(output,label)
    print(",epoch:%d,loss:%1.3f"%(epoch+1,loss.data[0]))
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

when I run `train.py`, I receive this error:

> self.rnn=nn.RNN(input_size=input_size,hidden_size=hidden_size,batch_first=True)
>       NameError: name 'input_size' is not defined

I don't know why I receive this error because I have `input_size=5` in the above lines of my code. could anybody help me? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of the variables defined in `train.py` (`num_classes`, `input_size`, ...) is the `train.py` itself. They are only visible in this file. The `model.py` is oblivious to these.
I suggest including these arguments in the constructor:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, hidden_size, input_size):
    # same
```

and then call the Model as:

```
model = Model(hidden_size, input_size)
```

Similarly, for other variables that you defined in `train.py` (and want to use them in `model.py`) you have to pass them as arguments to either their respective functions, or to the constructor and store them as attributes.